# Can I use classes to create/place elements in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create several elements, set properties and place them in the DOM, with vanilla js, in an easy-to-read way.

The way I’m doing it now is with normal functions doing all the DOM-editing, but one constrain is that I need to keep track of the current element and append it before I move on and create the next.

I’ve just beginning to learn about **classes** and tried to convert the idea into a class-structure but can’t get it to work.

**What’s the best practices here?** And if classes could do this, what’s the basic code to create and append a div?

Below is my code (that works) but I'm looking to improve the logic

```
let body = document.querySelector("body");

// keeping track of the current div
let currentDiv;

// create and add attr
function createDiv(){
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  currentDiv = newDiv;
}
function size(el, x, y){
  el.style.height = y;
  el.style.width = x;
}
function paintBG(el, clr){
  el.style.backgroundColor = clr;
}
function append(parent){
  parent.append(currentDiv);
}

// and then run the functions
createDiv();
size(currentDiv, "100%", "100px")
paintBG(currentDiv, "red");
append(body);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here but your functions just look like a duplicate version of the native ones. I don't think you need it, just use what Javascript is offering you without complicating it.

Comment: Well, I think I was wondering if there's any better way to do this when the amount of elements are stacking up, but maybe not!

Comment: @OskarEngstroem did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these methods to **[HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement#Methods)**
.Below is little example.

```js
let body = document.querySelector("body");
//create element with any tag  like create('tagname')
function create(tag){
 return document.createElement('div');
}
//append any number of child like body.append(elm1,elm2,elm3)
HTMLElement.prototype.append = function(...children){
 children.forEach(child => {
  this.appendChild(child);
 })
 return this;
}
//append the element to any other element 
HTMLElement.prototype.appendTo = function(parent){
 parent.appendChild(this);
 return this;
}
//change the size
HTMLElement.prototype.size = function(x,y){
 this.style.height = x;
 this.style.width = y;
 return this;
}
//changes color and background color
HTMLElement.prototype.paint = function(bgColor,textColor){
 this.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
 if(textColor) this.style.color = textColor;
 return this;
}
let myDiv = create('div').size('100px','100%').paint('blue','black').appendTo(body);
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks tons for this, gonna dive into learning how this works now when I have a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing concepts.

Classes in DOM is to group items that have a similar feature together, so they can be queried/updated in batch, as well as styled in the same way.

An element is an element, and it needs to be created as such.

A `<div class="header" />` and a `<span class="header" />` can share a class, but they will always be distinct elements, and thus, you cannot create them dynamically "by class"

In your example tho, I'd suggest using CSS instead of manipulating element styles individually.